# Sort a list of tuples, using nonlibrary sorting function (Python)

Tags: python, sorting

As the problems stated above, I need to use a nonlibrary sorting function, specifically a mergesort function I implemented in a previous assignment. I have my assignment working really well using `activity_arr.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2))`. However, the requirements are asking that I use this function:

```
def merge_sort(array):
''' Sorts an array using merge sort algorithm.'''
if len(array) > 1:
    # '//' is for "floor division", used in case array is filled with floats
    mid = len(array) // 2
    left = array[:mid]
    right = array[mid:]

    # Recursion to sort left and right half of array
    merge_sort(left)
    merge_sort(right)

    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0

    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] < right[j]:
            array[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            array[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1
    # Fill the rest of the array with remaining numbers in each array
    while i < len(left):
        array[k] = left[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1
    while j < len(right):
        array[k] = right[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1
```

I assume, I will have to modify it so that I can sort my list of tuples. An example of my list to sort is `example_list = [(1, 3, 4), (7, 2, 5), (1, 2, 1)]`. I want to sort in ascending order by the third element of the tuple. SO it should result in the following: `sorted_list = [(1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 4), (7, 2, 5)]`.

I am still just learning python and still have much to learn in CS in general. I have no idea how to make this change despite lots of research I mostly find people saying to use .sort(). If I left out anything important please let me know! Any help or information for me to look up will be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an index based on which you want to sort array of tuples.
For example, if you want to sort array based on index 2(indexing starts from 0), you can use it as: `merge_sort(example_list,2)`. Idea is simple, you have to compare element based on index given, like I have done it here:
    `if left[i][index] < right[j][index]:`

```
def merge_sort(array,index):         #edit here
''' Sorts an array using merge sort algorithm.'''
if len(array) > 1:
    # '//' is for "floor division", used in case array is filled with floats
    mid = len(array) // 2
    left = array[:mid]
    right = array[mid:]

    # Recursion to sort left and right half of array
    merge_sort(left,index)        #edit here
    merge_sort(right,index)       #edit here

    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0

    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i][index] < right[j][index]:      #edit here
            array[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            array[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1
    # Fill the rest of the array with remaining numbers in each array
    while i < len(left):
        array[k] = left[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1
    while j < len(right):
        array[k] = right[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1
```

Comment: Wow, I feel silly. That was such a simple solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can accept it as an answer, if this is what you wanted.